# Node server stops in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm getting error:

```
Ensure the following: - Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root - Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
```

server stops after 99.83% bundle lode.

Comment: refer [This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/304) issue and make changes accordingly. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: are you running node using `run 'npm start' from react-native root`?

Comment: yes, i run this command @c-chavez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue by increasing the cache size of `max_old_space_size`. in .bash_profile

Code:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```